# node_redis - how to get the TTL for a key?

Tags: node-redis

Project page: https://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis

It's possible to set an expiration for a key with:

```
client.set('key', 'value!', 'EX', 10);
```

Is there a way to get (read) the expiration of am existing key?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [ttl](https://redis.io/commands/ttl) function to get the remaining time until a key is expired. Note that you should promisify the function or use callbacks to get the result. An example code block in an **async** function would be like this:

```
const { promisify } = require('util');
const ttl = promisify(client.ttl).bind(client);
client.set('key', 'value!', 'EX', 10);
const remaingTime = await ttl('key');
```